# Schema.org price and SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdfa

I have the following HTML with Schema.org RDFa:

```xhtml
<li class="product" typeof="s:Product">
  <a href="item.php?id=227">
     <img property="s:img" src="http://www.test.com/pictures/227.jpg"></a>
  <h2 property="s:name">Example name</h2>
  <div property="s:brand">Examplebrand</div>
  <div property="s:model">Examplemodel</div>
  <div rel="s:offers">
    <div class="description" typeof="s:Offer">
      <div property="s:price">79,00</div>
      <div property="s:priceCurrency" content="EUR"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div property="s:productID" content="NQ==">
    <div rel="s:seller">
      <div class="description" typeof="s:Organization">
        <div property="s:name">Shop1</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

After loading the page I want to use SPARQL to select all the products which are (for example) > €70,00.

But this only gives back NULL:

```
PREFIX s: <http://schema.org/>
SELECT   ?a ?price
WHERE {
  ?a s:price ?price.
  FILTER (?price > 70).
}
```

I think it's not interpreting the price as an price/float. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does your model contains data which you query? can you partially print it out?

Comment: Have you tried using "79.00" as price value? I'm guessing it may depend on the SPARQL implementation or locale whether "79,00" is interpreted as float.

Comment: On revisiting your question: do other queries work, i.e. do only price queries not work? (Do you define the prefix `s:` to be `http://schema.org/` in the RDFa?)

Answer (score 1):

The XHTML isn't enough for us to get the corresponding RDF data from the RDFa.  I've filled out your XHTML into the following.  Note that I've make the `s` prefix be `http://schema.org/` based on your SPARQL query.  However, if those prefixes don't line up in your data, that would be an easy place for things to break down.

```xml
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/DTD/xhtml-rdfa-2.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      version="XHTML+RDFa 1.1"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:s="http://schema.org/"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
                          http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/SCHEMA/xhtml-rdfa-2.xsd"
      lang="en"
      xml:lang="en">
  <head><title>Some title</title></head>
  <body>
    <li class="product" typeof="s:Product">
      <a href="item.php?id=227">
        <img property="s:img" src="http://www.test.com/pictures/227.jpg"/></a>
      <h2 property="s:name">Example name</h2>
      <div property="s:brand">Examplebrand</div>
      <div property="s:model">Examplemodel</div>
      <div rel="s:offers">
        <div class="description" typeof="s:Offer">
          <div property="s:price">79,00</div>
          <div property="s:priceCurrency" content="EUR"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div property="s:productID" content="NQ==">
        <div rel="s:seller">
          <div class="description" typeof="s:Organization">
            <div property="s:name">Shop1</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </body>
</html>
```

Putting that into the [W3C's RDFa distiller](http://www.w3.org/2007/08/pyRdfa/), we can get this RDF:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:s="http://schema.org/"
  xmlns:xhv="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#"
  xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.test.com/pictures/227.jpg">
    <s:img xml:lang="en"></s:img>
  </rdf:Description>
  <s:Product>
    <s:seller>
      <s:Organization>
        <s:name xml:lang="en">Shop1</s:name>
      </s:Organization>
    </s:seller>
    <s:productID xml:lang="en">NQ==</s:productID>
    <s:model xml:lang="en">Examplemodel</s:model>
    <s:offers>
      <s:Offer>
        <s:priceCurrency xml:lang="en">EUR</s:priceCurrency>
        <s:price xml:lang="en">79,00</s:price>
      </s:Offer>
    </s:offers>
    <s:name xml:lang="en">Example name</s:name>
    <s:brand xml:lang="en">Examplebrand</s:brand>
  </s:Product>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Looking at the RDF, it's easy to see why the price is being interpreted as a string:

```xml
<s:price xml:lang="en">79,00</s:price>
```

The property value is a string, and a string with a language tag at that!  You can specify the datatype easily, however, by adding the namespace and a `datatype` attribute:

```xml
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      version="XHTML+RDFa 1.1"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      ...>
  ...
  <div property="s:price" datatype="xsd:float">79,00</div>
  ...
</html>
```

However, the comma notation isn't actually legal for the `xsd:float` type, so you'll actually need to specify a `content` attribute too, as in:

```xml
<div property="s:price" datatype="xsd:float" content="79.00">79,00</div>
```

After those changes, you'll get this RDF:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
  xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
  xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
  xmlns:s="http://schema.org/"
  xmlns:xhv="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml/vocab#"
  xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>
  <s:Product>
    <s:productID xml:lang="en">NQ==</s:productID>
    <s:model xml:lang="en">Examplemodel</s:model>
    <s:brand xml:lang="en">Examplebrand</s:brand>
    <s:offers>
      <s:Offer>
        <s:priceCurrency xml:lang="en">EUR</s:priceCurrency>
        <s:price rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float">79.00</s:price>
      </s:Offer>
    </s:offers>
    <s:name xml:lang="en">Example name</s:name>
    <s:seller>
      <s:Organization>
        <s:name xml:lang="en">Shop1</s:name>
      </s:Organization>
    </s:seller>
  </s:Product>
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.test.com/pictures/227.jpg">
    <s:img xml:lang="en"></s:img>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

After those changes, your query works just fine with no modifications:

```
$ arq --data data3.rdf --query query.sparql 
------------------------------------------------------------
| a    | price                                             |
============================================================
| _:b0 | "79.00"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#float> |
------------------------------------------------------------
```